# CounterStrike passing starting parameters to shortcut

Tags: counter-strike

i want to make counter-strike shortcut with connect parameter when game stats automatically connect to server

I have tried -connect xx.xx.xx.xx:27015 but i does not works

Comment: This is nearly identical to a question we had about Counter-Strike: Source (perhaps you are also playing CS:S and just mistagged?) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63114/13845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) you should do it like that:

```
steam://connect/<ip address>:<port>
```

It can be a simple .bat file or a shortcut for a browser that will load that link. Other option is to use this argument:

```
+connect <ip address>:<port>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Counter-Strike launch parameter is "+connect"  not "-connect".

Full list of launch parameters are located here: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Examples

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `-connect` to `+connect` as per the [Valve Wiki article on Command Line Options](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Command-line_parameters)

Comment: I'm not at home to test right now, but that should work (probably)